# Groovy methods that resemble LINQ's DefaultIfEmpty and FirstOrDefault

Tags: linq, groovy

Does Groovy have any methods (out-of-the-box) that resemble the DefaultIfEmpty or FirstOrDefault methods found in LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DefaultIfEmpty` can be covered by:

```
def list = []
def defaultIfEmpty = list ?: [ 'was empty' ]
```

`FirstOrDefault` is trickier, as I believe it returns the default value for a given type if there is no first element in the list... However, in Groovy (as it stands), there's no way of detecting the default type of the object (unless it is a native type)

You could do:

```
Integer defaultIfEmpty = list[ 0 ] ?: 0
```

It should be noticed however that the `elvis operator ?:` works on [Groovy truth](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Truth), so if the element on the left of the operator evaluates to false in Groovy (whether it be `null`, an empty list or string, the number 0, etc) it will return the right hand side)

It should also be noted that I am not a .NET expert, so may have the functionality of these two functions incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, I found out that .find() behaves almost similar to .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Yeah, you'd just need to supply a default if `find()` returns null. And better might be `list?.find()` which will also return null if `list` is null :-)

Comment: Wrote a simple defaultIfEmpty that works for most Collection types.

`Collection.metaClass.defaultIfEmpty = { val ->
 if (delegate.isEmpty()) {
  def myClone = delegate.clone
  myClone << val
  return myClone
 } else {
  return delegate
 }
}

def x = []
println x.defaultIfEmpty(5).find()`

Comment: @Wytze is this comparable? `Collection.metaClass.defaultIfEmpty = { val -> delegate ?: [ val ] }` ;-)